# Increment column header text Datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this code below that supposed to create a new column on datagridview everytimes a button is clicked, now that when a button is clicked a column named `"New Column 1"` will be generated but the thing is I was expecting for the `"New Column 1"` to be increment to `"New Column 1" "New Column 2" "New Column 3" ...` when a button is clicked for greater than once but `"New Column 1"` still appears even on multiple clicks.

What I've tried so far,

```
private void guna2Button4_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        guna2DataGridView2.Columns.Clear();

        // Add new column
        string file_path = @"C:\MAIN_TEXT_LOCATION\" + label3.Text + "\\" + label4.Text;
        using (StreamWriter swq = File.AppendText(file_path)) {
            var curr = 0;
            curr++;
            swq.Write("[" + "New Column " + (curr) + "]");
        }
        // Redefine data source
        retrieve_data();
}
```

I believe I have missing some crucial piece of code that I have to add in order to make it works but since I'm a novice I couldn't think further in order to make it works.

Comment: Your code uses a function scoped variable `(curr)` that gets defined each time you invoke the function `(var curr = 0;)`. You can define this outside the function's scope and increment it each time the function is invoked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
  int curr = 0; 
    private void guna2Button4_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            guna2DataGridView2.Columns.Clear(); 
            // Add new column
            string file_path = @"C:\MAIN_TEXT_LOCATION\" + label3.Text + "\\" + label4.Text;
            using (StreamWriter swq = File.AppendText(file_path)) {
                
                curr++;
                swq.Write("[" + "New Column " + (curr) + "]");
            }
            // Redefine data source
            retrieve_data();
    }
```

Comment: It works. So the logic is that I have to assign the `curr` variable before the button click event function, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution which gets the last number (int) in a string and increments the number by 1.

Add the following class to your project

```
public static class Helpers
{
    public static string NextValue(this string sender)
    {
        string value = Regex.Match(sender, "[0-9]+$").Value;
        return sender[..^value.Length] + (long.Parse(value) + 1)
            .ToString().PadLeft(value.Length, '0');
    }
}
```

Add a private int variable in the form `private int _columnIndex = 0;` to keep track of the last number for creating a new column.

In the form add `using System.Text.RegularExpressions;` then here in a button click event add a new column

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private int _columnIndex = 0;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void NewColumnButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(
            $"newColumnName{_columnIndex +1}", 
            $"New Column {_columnIndex}".NextValue());
        _columnIndex++;
    }
}
```

I expanded the columns in the screenshot after creating the columns manually.

[image]